# Аналог $_POST["название"] в HTTP сервисах 1с или как получить параметры(переменные) запроса в http-сервисе 1с

Tags: php, http, 1с

Проще говоря хочу обратиться к 1с конфигурации POST либо GET запросом через Android с языком java и в http-сервисе получить поля переданные запросом, чтобы на основании полученных данных создать документ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пишете в 1с сами - то смотрите в синтакс помошнике объект httpСервисЗапрос, который прилетает параметром в виде объекта в методы http сервиса. Из него можно вытащить три типа параметров, одни это заголовки (headers), другие именно параметры (Query string, .../object1?param1=4&param2=3, скорее всего вам нужны они если используете ретрофит и аннотацию @Query для параметра, свойство запроса ПараметрыЗапроса), третьи это параметры задаваемые в шаблоне url (/myservice/{тип}/{номер}, свойство запроса ПараметрыURL, если в ретрофите используете @Path аннотацию).